# socket c client doesn't receive string

Tags: c, sockets

This is the snippet of **client** code:

```
connect(DescrittoreClient, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

strcpy(Buffer, filename);

send(DescrittoreClient, Buffer, strlen(Buffer), 0);
fd = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY,0644);

while ((nread = read(DescrittoreClient, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer))) != 0) {
    write(fd, Buffer, nread);
    memset(Buffer,0,sizeof(Buffer));
}
int gg;
while( (gg = recv(DescrittoreClient, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), 0)) == -1) continue;
printf("%d\n", gg);
printf("Risposta del server: %s\n", Buffer);

close(DescrittoreClient);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

And this is the snippet of the **server** code:

```
while(1){

    rc = recv(DescrittoreClient, filename, sizeof(filename), 0);

    fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);

    fstat(fd, &stat_buf);

    offset = 0;
    rc = sendfile(DescrittoreClient, fd, &offset, stat_buf.st_size);
    if (rc != stat_buf.st_size) {
        fprintf(stderr, "incomplete transfer from sendfile: %d of %d bytes\n", rc, (int)stat_buf.st_size);
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(Buffer, "Dati inviati correttamente");
    if( (send(DescrittoreClient, Buffer, strlen(Buffer), 0)) == -1){
        printf("Errore nell'invio della stringa\n");
        close(DescrittoreClient);
        close(fd);
        exit(1);
    }

}
close(DescrittoreServer);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

This is the **expected** behaviour:

```
Client --Give me file X--> Server
Server --send the file X--> Client
Server -->send string "File has been sent"--> Client
```

But this is the **real** behaviour:

```
Client --Give me file X--> Server
Server --send the file X--> Client
Server -->_NOTHING_--> Client
```

So the problem is that the client doesn't receive "File has been sent". I've checked if the problem is server's side but it isn't (in fact the server send the string)

Comment: Too much code! Reduce it to a minimum while still reproducing the problem.

Comment: What is (Buffer) declared as?

Comment: if read() returns a negative value, the subsequent write() call is going to try to write (size_t)-1 bytes into your file, which will probably crash your client program.

Comment: Calling memset(Buffer, 0, sizeof(Buffer)) isn't necessary (or helpful) since you never use any bytes from Buffer that you read() didn't just write to anyway.

Comment: Having the client's recv() call in a while(recv_result==-1) continue loop like that is asking for a spinloop (i.e. your client app hangs up and uses 100% of the CPU forever) whenever there is an error on the socket.  If recv() returns -1, you should instead just fail with an error message.  (the exception would be if you are using non-blocking I/O and errno was set to EWOULDBLOCK, but it looks to me like you are using blocking I/O here, so that shouldn't apply to your case)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Buffer is declared as `char Buffer[1024];`

Comment: the client doesn't crash, in fact the file is received but the string from the server isn't received and i don't understad why!

Comment: How does your receiving code know when the bytes of the file have ended and the bytes of the string begin?  Most likely you'll find that the bytes of your string got lumped in with the file data and are present now at the end of the received file... :^/

Comment: in fact i've seen that this happened :( xD how i can prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(based on the comments above) -- the thing to realize is that TCP communication is 100% stream based, with no built-in framing.  That means that all the TCP layer does is make sure that the receiver receives the bytes in the same order that the sender sent them -- but it does *not* guarantee that the bytes will be received in the same intervals as they were sent.  (For example, if you send() 10 bytes, then 20 bytes, then 50 bytes, the receiver might receive all 80 bytes at once, or 63 bytes followed 17 bytes, or any other combination of recv()s that sum up to 80 bytes total).

Therefore in order to send multiple separate items in such a way that the receiver can interpret them correctly, you need to define your own rules for framing the data.  In your case you need to send *n* bytes of file data, followed by a string, and what your receiving program needs to know is how many bytes of file data to expect.  That way, once it has received (that many) bytes, it knows the remaining bytes are string data and won't just write them to the file.

My suggestion would be to send the file's size first (either as a 4-byte integer, or an 8-byte long if you need to support file sizes greater than 4 gigabytes).  Then the receiving code would be like this:

1. Receive 4 bytes
2. Interpret those four bytes as an integer (you may want to pass this value through htonl() on the sender and ntohl() on the receiver, in order to avoid possible endian-ness issues here)
3. Receive N bytes and write them to the file
4. Receive any remaining bytes as a string.